# How to add OnClick() for buttons in ListView of android?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, simplecursoradapter

This is my app.When clicking new button it will display the questions one by one and if we click the options(A,B,C,D)i should display correct or incorrect.For questions i did the coding now suggest me for options.

[image]

I have 5textviews and 4buttons in a xml file,data for those are being populated from database so i used ListView and SimpleCursorAdapter.It all works fine.Now i want to write OnClick functions for the buttons that are in the Xml file.I couldnt add SetOnClickListener as it displays an error "Couldnt fine the resource id" it displays as the buttons are available in the different xml.
How to assign OnClick() for those buttons?

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor c1;
Button b1;
String from[] = {"_id", "optn1", "optn2", "optn3", "optn4", "ab"};
int[] to = {R.id.textView3, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6, R.id.textView7, R.id.textView8, R.id.textView10};
int i = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ques(_id TEXT,optn1 TEXT ,optn2 TEXT,optn3 TEXT,optn4 TEXT,qno INTEGER,ab INTEGER)");
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {//this onclick is to display the texts only if the button is clicked not as soon as the app is executed
    if (v == b1) {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("quiz1.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        if (c1 != null) {
            i = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("qno"));
        }
        c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ques WHERE qno>'" + i + "' ORDER BY qno LIMIT 1", null);
        SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.compo_list, c1, from, to);
        ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        l1.setAdapter(sca);
        sca.changeCursor(c1);
        t1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
  Layout.XML
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="QUESTION"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:phoneNumber="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="D"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4" />
```

waiting for suggestion.It will so grateful if u help me out.thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but where is the part where you use `setOnClick` ? I can see only querying to database and setting adapter to listView

Comment: Actually buttons are in the "R.layout.compo_list" XML file.Its the components that are passed to ListView.

Comment: please update your question with current information. Could you provide missing parts like this layout you have just mentioned?

Comment: The listed error is ""Couldnt fine the resource id". Which code is that? Is it at "new SimpleCursorAdapter"

Comment: No.here is my LogCat`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.shark.lvquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)`It shows when i try to `b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);`below button 1

Comment: @Sharathkumar, The code you're telling us about the error was not even posted. This might make it difficult to help you. Anyway I posted an answer. Hope it helps...

Comment: No sir actually i am trying to validate a button which is not in the MainActivity but it is available in the Layout file so when i try to validate it i get any exception.I posted the code in my question which does not contain any errors.

Comment: One problem of this code design is that you already have code setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). And now in the Activity, you want to inflate another xml file. I think this is confusing or will not work. I'll post another answer. And you're right about my previous answer, my mistake.

Comment: Ya that only its not working and i dont know how to make it work.Thanks alot for the help.I will be more happy if u suggest even different concept to achieve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80970/discussion-between-sharath-kumar-and-the-original-android).

Comment: Can u help me out with this sir.i did as u suggested me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930383/onclick-in-cursoradapter-doesnt-gets-incremented-are-refreshed-on-clicks-in-an

Comment: My ques is simple @The original android...I have onClick() in myAdap class,it should print increment values on clicking the button.Plz suggest some way for it?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placed a new activity named ListViewAdapter which extends BaseAdapter and Overrided the functions in it.Placed all the OnClick() activities inside this class and it works perfect.
Ping me if anyone need more info on it.

Answer (score 0):

Do it from your listview.

```
    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you get the children of the ListView iterate over them and if it's an instance of Button cast it to a button and call setOnClickListener on that button. I'll give you an example in a sec

Comment: @Sharathkumar - Anywhere after you set your adaptor, Michael P has also helped you to your full solution as what I have posted where work for any item clicked, including your textviews, it was more to point you in the direction of how to use an onclick from a listview

Comment: I dont know how to do what michael says.can any one explain or suggest some links to it?

Comment: I don't believe.. How is it possible to post so low quality answers without checking if it will works... @dave did you checked this? OP wanted help with setting click listener on buttons in listview children. Of course it won't work if you just find view in listView's item. You must use also `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" ` in root of item's layout.

Comment: @deadfish, I am not in the practice of coding for other people, I like to give them a starting point so they can learn on there own, this is the generally accepted way of handling onclick listeners from listviews

Comment: @dave You are right but following Your way, OP will not be able handle click of button but only list item :)

Comment: Exactly @deadfish.i tryed the code it does the same thing as the button in parent does.i will add the image to the ques now.

Comment: My ques is simple @dave...I have onClick() in myAdap class,it should print increment values on clicking the button.Plz suggest some way for it?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

About the code:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.compo_list, c1, from, to);
ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

When you call `SimpleCursorAdapter` with the layout xml `compo_list`, it does not inflate the layout. It is meant for the **Adapter** and *not the Activity*. Therefore you should get runtime error on `findViewById(R.id.listView)`

Suggestions:

- In the SimpleCursorAdapter, copy code findViewById for the Adapter. This is a common technique.
- Don't try to inflate in the Activity, `setContentView` did that already. This is confusing and much work for it. Normally inflating is done in a Fragment. In the Fragment, you can call and create new instance of SimpleCursorAdapter.
- There is code already `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in the Activity. This is normally your only layout file that you can place the UI elements in.

EDIT:
Per your suggestion, here are good webpage tutorials on **ListView**:

1. **ArrayAdapter** @ [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)
2. **SimpleCursorAdapter** with ListView [Using CursorAdapters](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_4_-_using_cursoradapters/)

**Notes**:

- Webpage 1 introduces using ListView with popular ARrayAdapter.
- Page 2 introduces using CursorAdapters, assumes you know how to use ListView and basic Adapters.

Code snippet from Link page 1:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position
       User user = getItem(position);    
       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
       if (convertView == null) {

          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
       }
```

Notice the inflate method in the code snippet. This is the layout that you want to use for `R.layout.compo_list`.

I hope this helps and explains your issue. It seems you still have some work to do.    Good luck and have fun...

Comment: u are telling to do with fragment and not to inflate with XML?

Comment: @Sharathkumar, Create a fragment and inflate the layout xml in it instead of the main activity. I made few edits in my post on Suggestions, to clarify. There are good samples/tutorials on the subject of Adapters and Listview.

Comment: Can u tell me some way to contact u in PM?if u are ok with it.

Comment: @Sharathkumar, I added some notes and explanations under the EDIT section. I know it's a lot to read. I suggest that after you fix the runtime error that you posted, post another one if you have problems with the Adapter/ListView or CursorAdapter.  Again I hope my post helps. You may click the "useful" icon, if you think so.

Comment: @Sharathkumar, Is the original question resolved yet before moving on to your next problem or post? It seems you have forgotten about this posted answer. Otherwise tell me if the answer is helpful or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
      int position, long id) {
    final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    t1.setText(String.valueOf(item));

  }

});
```

Comment: it won't work if positions count isnt equal listView's children count

Comment: My ques is simple @Deadfish...I have onClick() in myAdap class,it should print increment values on clicking the button.Plz suggest some way for it?Thanks!